# Users, roles, and privileges are lost after upgrading neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm following the upgrade procedure described on the [documentation website](https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/upgrade/upgrade-4.1/deployment-upgrading/) of neo4j. I restored the database offline with `neo4j-admin load`.
Now, after restarting the database, all users, roles, and privileges from my previous database are gone, though the data is the same.

How do I keep the users, roles, and privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the [online backup](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/online-backup/) of neo4j database can solve this problem with param `--include-metadata`. Note that after restoring the database, run the script `estore_metadata.cypher` (see the doc [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-backup/))